# CSS image width 100%, but still has some background

Tags: html, css

I have the following website:

[www.thewhozoo.com](http://www.thewhozoo.com)

It works fine on a desk top, but for some reason on a mobile device's browser, it has a grey bar down the side.

[image]

I have the following code:

**css**

```
body {
    background-color: #4B5961;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ),url('../images/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
  }
```

**html**

```
<body>

    <div id="image-head" class="top-container">
```

The grey line down the side is the same as the background color of the body (`#4B5961`).

As you can see, I have the body width and the background image width both set at `100%`. So I would not expect to see the grey line. I think it is a result of the scroll bar.

If anyone can advise how I can remove this, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Dude, that's the scrollbar, right? Oh wait, no.

Comment: It is a result of the scroll bar I think, but it's not the scroll bar. The scroll bar hovers above this when scrolling, and disappears when not scrolling.

Comment: Remove the padding with `.wz-title`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your style this css rule, take out the `padding-left: 10px;`:

```
.wz-title {
    color: #B2D137;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
    font-size: 110%;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you! My bad, I appreciate your help here, that was the problem.  I will mark this as the answer as soon as it allows me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the padding with `.wz-title`. For some reason, removing padding fixes it.

```css
.wz-title {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Here:

[image: preview]

Comment: Hi Praveen, thank you, that's the reason. Daniel below also spotted my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow-x:hidden; on your body, that'll fix it:

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body, body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By using above code you will never face any problem with **padding** ever. :)